# after a integer input, I want to concatenate two strings, one already initialize and another one is user input

Tags: java

```
int i = 4;
String s ="Hi ";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter Integer");
int m=scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("enter string");
*String t = scan.next();
**String t = scan.nextLine();

System.out.println(i+m);
System.out.println(s+t);
```

when I use *scan.next() then it will only read a single word, another side when I use **scan.nextLine() it will directly show the output

Comment: why are you using *?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: `nextInt` let the `<enter>` in the buffer, so the next `nextLine` read that. Check the duplicate above for a complete answer.

Comment: Can you add this line: scan.nextLine(); after your int m = scan.nextInt(); just do that and let me know if it works.

Comment: * is only for description, * is not exist in code

Answer (score 0):

Call `nextLine()` after `nextint()` to consume `\n`.

```
int a = scanner.nextInt()
scanner.nextLine() // to flush end of line
 ... // Then read string
String s = scanner.next()
```

**The whole story**

After Entering a number, Say 5..
the stream looks like

`5\n`

When `nextInt()` is called,
the stream looks like

`\n`

After you enter string, say `hi

`\nhi`

After `next()` is called 
the stream looks like

`hi`

The cause of problem: `next()` consume till `\n`.
When it is called `\n` was first character in the stream. so it read empty string `""`.